# Need help trying to completely remove a "virus pertection software"

Tags: powershell

the company I work for is moving to a new virus protection software. I have been tasked with writing the tool that will remove the older virus software since the standard uninstall doesn't seem to remove the entire software package. I have searched around Stack Overflow and found many different examples of how to get different parts of this tool to work and have thrown them together in an attempt to make a working product. For a reason I have yet to figure out I can't seem to get anything to work. Here is what I have so far:

```
# This section launches Powershell as Admin

PS> Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs

if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }

PS >Read-Host "Press ENTER"
Press ENTER:

# This section uninstalls Vipre from the program files

$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
$_.Name -match "VIPRE BUSINESS AGNET" 
}

$app.Uninstall()

PS >Read-Host "Press ENTER"
Press ENTER:

# This section searches the Registry for all instances of Vipre and VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT and deletes them

gci HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "Vipre") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

gci HKCR: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "Vipre") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

gci HKCU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "Vipre") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item 

gci HKU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "Vipre") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item    


gci HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

gci HKCR: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

gci HKCU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item 

gci HKU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) 
-match "VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT") { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

PS >Read-Host "Press ENTER"
Press ENTER:
```

I have a pause, "Press Enter" to try and see what the command before it has done and even that doesn't seem to be working. As the screen flashes, I can tell there are errors being thrown, and then goes away.

My questions are:

What am I doing wrong? Are there syntax errors and what are they?

Thank you for all help.

**EDIT UPDATE**

My file now looks like this:

```
# This section launches Powershell as Admin

{ Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -verb RunAs; exit }

$code = {

# This section uninstalls Vipre from the program files

    $App = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like %"VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT"%"'
if ($App) 
{
$App.Uninstall()
}


# This section searches the Registry for all instances of Vipre and VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT and deletes them

Get-ChildItem HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

Get-ChildItem HKCR: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

Get-ChildItem HKCU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item 

Get-ChildItem HKU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item    


Get-ChildItem HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

Get-ChildItem HKCR: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

Get-ChildItem HKCU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item 

Get-ChildItem HKU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

}

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -noexit -verb runas -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

The PowerShell script seems to be at least trying to run now but then throws the error:

```
-verb : The term '-verb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ -verb runas -encodedCommand DQAKACAAIAAgAA0ACgAjACAAVABoAGkAcwAgAHMAZ ...
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-verb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried removing -verb from both the top and bottom of the script and that causes PowerShell to give me a bunch of commands that need to follow RUNAS.

Comment: I'd say your attempt is in vain. The procedures for removing AV software depend very heavily on which software you actually want to remove. Make a list of which programs have been installed and check the vendor homepage(s) for removal tools.

Comment: There are some typos and strange stuff in the code. And you have to wrap the whole code as `-command` for your powershell-process in the first line

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have gone over the vendors homepage and tried the steps they give. This works "mostly" but doesn't uninstall the program but rather disables it and leave a lot behind.

Comment: @restless1987 I am very new to PowerShell. What do you mean by wrap the whole code as -command

Comment: @restless1987 I did find the spelling error and have fixed that

Answer (score 0):

This here could work - but I have no idea what the first if-statement is supposed to do:

```
    # This section launches Powershell as Admin


if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }


$code = {
    Read-Host 'Press ENTER'
    Press ENTER:

    # This section uninstalls Vipre from the program files

    $app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object { 
        $_.Name -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGNET'  ##Typo 'AGNET'?
    }

    $app.Uninstall()

    Read-Host 'Press ENTER'
    Press ENTER:

    # This section searches the Registry for all instances of Vipre and VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT and deletes them

    Get-ChildItem HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

    Get-ChildItem HKCR: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

    Get-ChildItem HKCU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item 

    Get-ChildItem HKU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'Vipre') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item    


    Get-ChildItem HKLM: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

    Get-ChildItem HKCR: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

    Get-ChildItem HKCU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item 

    Get-ChildItem HKU: -rec -ea SilentlyContinue | % { if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match 'VIPRE BUSINESS AGENT') { $_.PsPath} } | Remove-Item  

    Read-Host 'Press ENTER'
    Press ENTER:
}

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -noexit -verb runas -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

Comment: from what I understand its supposed to raise the privileges of the account logged in

Comment: That is already done by `-verb runas`. With that you start as administrator

Comment: Now I get this error:     -verb : The term '-verb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -verb runas -encodedCommand DQAKACAAIAAgAA0ACgAjACAAVABoAGkAcwAgAHMAZ ...
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-verb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Man, sorry but your code is a mess...

Few remarks:

**1.** This is not the right way to execute powershell code... save your code text to .PS1 file then execute it on the remote machine like this:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File \\share\script.ps1
```

**2.** If you want to check for admin privileges, do it inside your code,

```
if (([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{
  ## if the user is admin the code will be executed
}

else
{
throw "This code must be run with admin privileges"
}
```

**3.**  Use `Get-WMIObject -Filter` Parameter - It will be much faster then Where-Object

```
$App = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter 'Name like %"VIPRE BUSINESS AGNET"%"'
    if ($App) 
    {
    $App.Uninstall()
    }
```

**4.** Don't Search the whole Registry to find this keys, as Ansgar Suggested, check at the vendor for specific keys, see chapter IV - "Removal of the VIPRE Agent's Registry Entries" on the vendor site in the following link:

https://support.threattracksecurity.com/support/solutions/articles/1000070667-how-to-manually-remove-a-vipre-business-agent

Comment: I totally understand my code is, more than likely, a mess, thus why I am posting it here for help. I have looked at the vendors site. The problem i am finding is depending on the age of the machine I have found as many as 150 different entries in the registry for this product. That's why I went with a search and remove rather than entering a line for each individual entry. I will try out your suggestions and thank you very much for the help.

Comment: We already have a network deployment tool to reach every PC in the company. It more a matter of getting the thing to work.